# QT Widgets Application over Remote Desktop loads very slow

Tags: performance, qt, remote-desktop, qtwidgets

I have a mysterious behavior with a Qt Widgets application. It runs fine when this application is started directly on the target system (Beckhoff PC with Windows) or on my development pc.
The same application runs on several identical target systems.
If the application is started via the Windows Remote Desktop, then on some systems it takes a very long time (approx. 10 minutes) until the QT Widgets application is loaded and started. It is as if the application is frozen.

The application only uses the standard elements (buttons, labels, text inputs, dropdowns etc).

I have no idea what I could change in the code.
Does anyone have an idea if this could have something to do with the remote desktop?

Could it have something to do with OpenGL?
Is this a known issue?
Is there a known solution for this?

Starting the app directly on the target system works fine.
I would expect the same behavior when starting the app via remote desktop.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has something to do with the remote connection. I think the target computer is too slow. You should check your settings. You will find more than enough answers on the net that you can test.

Comment: @MarcoF. What settings do you mean? The remote desktop settings? Can you give me a hint where to look or which settings you mean? I already searched a lot, but i did not found a solution.

Comment: I'm also just guessing. search for: "7 Tested Ways to Fix Remote Desktop Slow on Windows 10, 11"